# rails automatically change routes for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have the following sign-up form in my signup_path, which is mapped to to users#new

In my new.html.erb

```
            <%= form_for(@user) do |f|%>

                    <!---handles the error messages within the form. -->
                    <%= render "shared/error_messages"%>

                    <%= f.label :name%>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%></br>

                    <%= f.label :email%>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control'%></br>

                    <%= f.label :password%>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'%></br>

                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation"%>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %></br>

                    <%= f.submit "Create My Account!", class:"btn btn-theme btn-block"%>

                <%end%>
```

in my routes.rb

```
get "signup" => "users#new"
```

Right now I can successfully sign up new users at **localhost:3000/signup**, which is ideal. However, whenever I try to test the form by leaving some or all fields blank, it will redirect me to **localhost:3000/users**. I thought maybe something is off in my controller, but I can't find anything odd about it

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    # before accessing the only and edit RESTful thing, go to logged_in_user first. 
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user, only: [:destroy]


    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def new
        # create a new user!
        @user = User.new
    end

    def show
        # declare a user variable, assign it to the current user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            #before we watned to log the user in after they create their account, now we want them to activate their emails

            #log_in @user
            #flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
            #redirect_to @user

            @user.send_activation_email
            flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
            redirect_to login_url
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end
```

What am i doing wrong here? Why is the route changing? I tried to **redirect_to signup_path** as oppose to **render "new"**, but if I do that then the error messages would disappear, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your login form posts to `/users`, so when you `render "new"` the url shown is correct. If you want to change that behavior, you could add `post "signup" => "users#create"` to your routes so you could post the form to `/signup` which would display your desired url when you `render "new"` from the `create` action.

Comment: I added post "signup" => "users#create" to my routes, but unfortunately the behavior is still the same. Am I missing something, especially with the line " post the form to /signup..." ?

Comment: `<%= form_for(@user), url: '/signup' do |f| %>` should post to the correct location.

Comment: It's giving me an syntax error. I've tried both the way above and :url => signup_path, but both return syntax error. Is it something new with rails 4.1?

Comment: I fixed it ! turns out url needs to be inside the parameter for form_for like <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>